# ListView with dyamically selected per row layout

Tags: android, listview, layout, listactivity

Seen a lot of tutorials with all different types of layout, but not clear on how a layout could be dynamically applied based on the item.

Lets assume a list with items that derive from a common type like book, but a different subclass of book like paperback or audio book would get a completely different layout. So we would have one layout per class/type of object in the list.  Evey item has some common properties but others have some additional properties.

So for example

Row 1  Description Text   Clickable Button     ItemType = A
Row 2  Description Text   CheckBox             ItemType = C
Row 3  Description Text   Spinner              ItemType = B
Row 4  Description Text   Clickable Button     ItemType = A
Row 5  Description Text   Checkbox             ItemType = C

So essentially the item type is determining the layout.  ItemType A always have Clickable Item, ItemType C always CheckBox, ItemType B always a Spinner, and all layouts have a description text.  I have not seen how the layout would be dynamically applied to list elements based on an element of the array of data.  How could this be done or better yet is there a good example on this.  Thanks

Comment: Essentially what I am asking is how can we apply a different layout based on one or more fields in the data being rendered?  An Item Renderer that is dynamically selected based on the type of the item? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Listview with different layout for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen a few of these questions lately.  One solution is to override the `getView` method of the adapter and determine which layout to apply at runtime for each item in your list.  It's a fair amount of work, but it does what you want for the non-standard implementation that your asking for.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats what I was looking for.  Any thoughts on the Cursor based vs. Simple. As to which would be best.

Comment: I've only used `BaseAdapters` and `SimpleAdapters` (which is just an easy to use Base) for lists.  SimpleCursorAdapter inherits from base Adaptor, so I'm not sure what the advantages are.